# Pushing a ViewController Through a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a custom uiscrollview class that has certain views and buttons. When I press a button in this custom scrollview, I want to present a new viewcontroller. Since this scroll view is inside of a view controller, and the custom class doesn't have the authority to push view controllers like a navigation controller, how do I push a new view controller through this uiscrollview class without throwing an error? Whenever I create a new navigationcontroller and an instance of the viewcontroller that I want inside of the method for when the button is pressed, and I present that viewcontroller, I get an error. Also, all of this is programatic and dynamic, not though storyboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollView must be inside a viewController.

The best way to accomplish your scenario is to put the viewController that contains the scroller inside a navigationController, Then you can push to wharever you want.

Hope this may help

Comment: Init the scroller's button target in the controller itself, It should work.

Comment: I did, that is not the issue.

Comment: You didn't get me right. You can't navigate from a custom view. You have to do it from a UIViewController (that holds the scroller). Then you can you self.navigationController to push to the second controller. The implementation of your button must be in the first controller.

Comment: Oh, alright. Gosh, I thought I could work around that, but I guess not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to instantiate viewController through the storyboard, or directly from class, after that present it as a modal view controller from your source UIViewController like this

```
presentViewController:animated:
```

This possible leads to animation issues, that could be solved implementing your own animation

Comment: I have a viewcontroller that contains my custom scrollview. That scroll view is customized through a seperate class. In that class, I need to push another viewconrtoller to the screen. The problem is that I can't do it directly to the main navigationcontroller, and that I need to push the new viewcontroller through the custom scrollview class.

Comment: If your scroll view is on your UIViewController, you can try to access to UIViewController as superview property, and than push new UIViewController. Do you try to do like this ?

Comment: Try something like this

Comment: [Reference Image](https://imgur.com/e2NhaJo): This image shows that my schedulescrollview is seperate from my sportsviewcontroller, which handles all of the scrollviews. When the button is pressed, where the nslog says pressed, is where I call the action, but I can't figure out how to do this without throwing an error.

Comment: Get the self.superview, cast it to UIViewController, than get the navigation UIViewController, instantiate new one and push it

Comment: I did that: [Image](https://imgur.com/0Ta5Jnw), but I got an error that I couldn't do this, because I believe that you can never cast a uiview to a uiviewcontroller. Am I doing what you said incorrectly or...

Comment: Well, you shouldn't push into navigation UIViewController the new one navigation UIViewController. Firstly, you had to check is that superview is UIViewController, like is it equal to class of UIViewController. Secondly, if this will not work, you can have reference to your UIViewController in the custom scroll view as a solution